# Posting link on behalf of page thru Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am debugging on Graph API Explorer.

When I post a message `/{page-id}/feed message=This+is+a+test+message`, I can post this message as the page. But when I post a link `/{page-id}/feed link=http://link.com`, I can only post this link as the user.

Is there anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but when I add `actions={"name": "action", "link": "http"}` then it works.